# FUSE mounted Google Drive (via google-drive-ocamlfuse) for Wordpress and permission issues

Tags: permissions, wordpress, mount, fuse

My objective is to use Google Drive to store media files for a Wordpress multisite using Fuse, and so far I am able to mount Google Drive with google-drive-ocamlfuse as root.  I can mount the Google Drive as /mnt/google-drive and do cp, rm, mkdir, edit files as root, etc but am not able to change file suid/guid.

I cp -R the directory contents from /wordpress/wp-content/uploads to the /mnt/google-drive/wordpress/wp-content/uploads, and then mv the original uploads/ folder to uploads.original/, so I can make a symbolic link:

ln -s /mnt/google-drive/wordpress/wp-content/uploads uploads

When I try to uploads files through Upload New Media in Wordpress, I get an error:

“3.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2013/10. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

I have tried using -o allow_other but to no avail.  The suid/guid of the files on Google Drive are all root:root and I'm guessing that is why Wordpress is unable to write to it.  I have also tried using -o uid and gid flags but it doesn't change the resulting file or directory permissions on Google Drive.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

> Use the `WP-Stateless plugin` to serve Wordpress media files from your Google Cloud Storage bucket. You can have GCS bucket serve as a backup, a CDN, or have media files served directly & entirely off of GCS i.e. 'stateless mode' where no media files will be kept on your server's persistent disk.

There are limitations to running the mounted GCS bucket as a traditional file system. For one, [latency is an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse#latency-and-rsync) and you'd be [missing traditional filesystem features](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#missing-features) like renaming or permission modifications. George covers some details here: [Anyone using “Google Cloud Storage Fuse” in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137316/3998770)